# Export all Content Pages in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, export

How would I export all the records from Google Analytics on the content page? Right now I am limited to 500 at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Par for the course, found the answer directly after posting. You do this as follows:

1. Load the content page
2. Add `&limit=123456789` to the end of the query string and hit enter
3. Click "Export"
4. Click "CSV" - NB - Don't use CSV for Excel!

Thats all folks.